# How can I get a dbus message from other user's desktop program

Tags: c, linux, debian, dbus

### My problem:

1. In the debian system I logined with generic session.
2. I have a program A which is created a bus name "cn.com.notify.ring" with some methods func1, func2...
3. I have a program B call the func1 is success.
4. Now I have a other program C should run with **sudo -E C**
5. The problem is the program C can't find the session bus and can't call the methods. How can I do to solve this problem.

### I try:

I konw I need -E to get the **DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS**, and run **setuid()** to change the user id to generic, but I don't want to do this.

### My code:

```
g_bus_own_name(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
        "cn.com.notify.ring",
        G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_NONE,
        NULL,
        on_name_acquired,
        NULL,
        obj,
        NULL);
```